# Anylogic: Write parameter value into Database table

Tags: sql, anylogic

I'm trying to write the value of a parameter in Anylogic into a specific cell of a Database table. The parameter is declared in my main and gets its value through a specific calculation in  function. Now I want to store the calculated value in the Database table.

I tried using the

```sql
INSERT INTO query (executeStatement("INSERT INTO eu (country, capital) VALUES ('Croatia', 'Zagreb')"); --> example from help)
```

…but I'm not able to use the specific parameter in the query/as a VALUE. I can only write direct input (like 'Croatia'), but not the parameter. At the end I want the table to get the current value from the parameter and insert the value in the table.
I found an Insert connectivity tool in the help function, but unfortunately it's only available in the professional edition.

Does anyone have an idea how to handle this?
Thank you and have a great weekend!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I fully understood what you need but if what you want to do is simply insert values into a table, then what you've done inside your "`executeStatement`" is actually enough:

```sql
INSERT INTO eu (country, capital) VALUES ('Croatia', 'Zagreb')
```

If what you mean by "specific cell" is actually replacing the content of an existing field in a given row, you want to use `UPDATE` instead:

```sql
UPDATE eu SET country='New country', capital='New capital' WHERE <some criteria matching targeted row>
```

**WARNING**: don't forget the `WHERE` statement or every row of your table will be clobbered with these same new values.

And if what you want to do is inserting one or more new rows filled with something that already exists in the database, then you can construct your dataset directly from a SELECT query:

```sql
INSERT INTO eu (country, capital)
 SELECT country_field, capital_field
   FROM some_table
  WHERE some_criteria
```

The `SELECT` query following the `UPDATE` statement can be absolutely anything. It may also refer to the same table if needed. The only requirement is to form rows that have the same structure and same type (at least compatible) than the targeted fields.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, the update statement seems promising! I also updated my question, so hopefully my problem is a bit clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust your String that defines the SQL statement.

Instead of

```
"INSERT INTO eu (country, capital) VALUES ('Croatia', 'Zagreb')"
```

you write

```
"INSERT INTO eu (country, capital) VALUES ('"+myParam1+", '"+myParam2+"')"
```

Assuming you have 2 params of type String that hold string text.

Your dbase column type must match the parameter (or variable) type you want to write

Be VERY careful with the ' and " signs as above

Comment: Hi Benjamin, thanks for your comment! I have two other questions regarding my code, I will put my code into another answer in this thread. Would be great if you could help me :)

Comment: @Pumluk please put new questions as new SOF questions, this is not a discussion board, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask :)  (And if this answer was helpful, please upvote it for others to see)

Comment: thanks for your tip! I will go through the "how to ask" :) Unfortunately my upvote is not displayed, due to missing reputation... I put my questions yesterday as new SOF questions, after I realized that that's the right way to do it.